# Breaking change from between AngularJS 1.2 and 1.4?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

The following code works in Angular 1.2 but breaks in 1.4 with error Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MyController' is not a function, got undefined. The code comes from the book "ng-book", and a live working example can be found here: http://jsbin.com/uHiVOZo/1/edit?html,output.

What changed?

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        {{ clock }}
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function MyController($scope) {
            $scope.clock = new Date();
            var updateClock = function() {
                $scope.clock = new Date();
            };
            setInterval(
                function() {
                    $scope.$apply(updateClock);
                },
                1000
            );
            updateClock();
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

(Replace https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js with https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.js in the jsbin link)

Comment: FYI, using the `$interval` service allows you to update the `$scope` without needing to use `$scope.$apply()` http://jsbin.com/zavefaqiju/2/edit (edit: wrong url)

Comment: Interesting. Can angular inject a service based on the parameter name now, or is the second parameter to a controller always the $interval service?

Comment: All the stuff that Angular 'registers', controllers, services, filters, directives, config, can take any number of 'providers' as arguments, in any order. Once you register whatever it is your making (controller, for instance) angular will inject that object, just like `$scope`

Comment: Here's a super simple example of creating and registering a service, then dropping it into the main controller http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/rVjbEX?editors=101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't know any version of Angular allowed you to create a controller without first creating a module. In any case, instantiating a module and registering the controller fix your problem. [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xipayurufu/2/edit)

Add this to your app decalartion in html:

```
ng-app="app"
```

Modify your script:

```
angular.module('app', []) // this creates a module

function MyController () { ... }

// register controller to module
angular.module('app').controller('MyController', MyController)
```

Comment: Reading further, the next section was on modules. Apparently, in version 1.2 of Angular, declaring a controller without an application module assigned it to the global namespace, which would cause all kinds of testing issues. I'm glad they changed it.

Answer (score 0):

See in https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

"Migrating from 1.2 to 1.3
Controllers
Due to 3f2232b5, $controller will no longer look for controllers on window. The old behavior of looking on window for controllers was originally intended for use in examples, demos, and toy apps. We found that allowing global controller functions encouraged poor practices, so we resolved to disable this behavior by default.

To migrate, register your controllers with modules rather than exposing them as globals:
"

Before:

```
function MyController() {
  // ...
}
```

After:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MyController', [function() {
  // ...
}]);
```